# failed to install dompdf package in laravel 5.2.45

Tags: laravel, dompdf

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\selfcomply>composer require dompdf/dompdf
Using version ^0.8.1 for dompdf/dompdf
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize

[37;41m                                                           [39;49m
[37;41m  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  [39;49m
[37;41m  Class 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider' not found  [39;49m
[37;41m                                                           [39;49m

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

i am getting this error when i install dompdf package in my project,
can anyone help me with this.

Comment: The issue isn't with dompdf, but your application. It seems you have told it to load Entrust's service provider in `config/app.php` without having it installed.